# For given permutation, find solutions for $x^3=\sigma\in S_{9}$

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

We have the given permutation 
$$\sigma =\left({\begin{array}{*{20}c}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\ 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 3\end{array}}\right)\ $$

Find how many solutions have the equation

$x^3=\sigma\in S_{9}$

The cycles of it are (1 4 7)(2 5 8)(3 6 9).

Can somebody help me understand how to solve it? Please!

Comment: Hint: $x$ must be a $9$-cycle. (Can you see why?)

Comment: @Jordan Green because it’s an S9 or a multiple of 3 cycles?

Comment: Think about the order.   Since $x^9 = \sigma^3 = e$, we know that the order of $x$ must divide $9$.  Thus, the order of $x$ is $9$, $3$, or $1$.  We can rule out $1$ and $3$ because If $|x| =1$ or $|x| = 3$, we ’d have $\sigma = e$.

Comment: Ok makes sense but how do I find how many solutions are? I don’t understand